# How do I restrict my CASE statement to 1 row per evaluation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have a simple query with 2 rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.OrderNo,
    CASE
        WHEN od.PartNo LIKE '%Amend%' AND od.User_Currency2 IS NOT NULL THEN od.User_Currency2
        WHEN od.PartNo LIKE '%Amend%' AND od.User_Currency1 IS NOT NULL THEN od.User_Currency1
        ELSE o.OrderTotal
        END AS [OrderTotal] 
FROM OrderDet od
   JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
WHERE o.OrderNo LIKE '%E'
ORDER BY o.OrderNo
```

In my CASE statement, for every order, if the 1st condition is met, I want it to return just that and ignore the other 2 options, same for condition # 2, and if the first 2 conditions fail, then default to the ELSE

Problem is I'm getting multiple rows per order, as you can see below:

[image]

How can I restrict to just 1 record per order?  I thought the CASE statement evaluated in order and would spit out just 1 value, but in my case, each order is returning multiple results from the CASE statement per order

Comment: The case expression returns a single value PER ROW which is what this is doing. For order 20228E which value of OrderTotal do you want?

Comment: The priority is based on how I listed them in my CASE statement, so I want the User_Currency2 field first if it's not null, then Curr1, then if both those are null, then OrderTotal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a series of queries unioned and filtered by the User_Currency2/User_Currency1 values like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.OrderNo,
    od.User_Currency2 AS [OrderTotal]
FROM OrderDet od
   JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
WHERE
  o.OrderNo LIKE '%E' AND
  od.PartNo LIKE '%Amend%' AND
  od.User_Currency2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.OrderNo,
    od.User_Currency2 AS [OrderTotal]
FROM OrderDet od
   JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
WHERE
  o.OrderNo LIKE '%E' AND
  od.PartNo LIKE '%Amend%' AND
  od.User_Currency2 IS NULL AND
  od.User_Currency1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.OrderNo,
    od.OrderTotal
FROM OrderDet od
   JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
WHERE
  o.OrderNo LIKE '%E' AND
  od.PartNo LIKE '%Amend%' AND
  od.User_Currency2 IS NULL AND
  od.User_Currency1 IS NULL
ORDER BY
  o.OrderNo
```